# Selecting the same column from the same table multiple times in the same statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am converting a VB6 app to C# with an SQL Server back end. The app includes a very general query editor that allows the user to write any select query and return the results visually in a grid control. Some of the tables have several hundred columns (poor design, I know but I have no control over this). A typical use case for an admin user would be to

```
select * from A_Table_With_Many_Columns
```

However, while they want to be able to view all the data, they are particularly interested in 2 columns and they want these to be displayed as the first 2 columns in the grid (instead of 67th and 99th for example) so instead they execute the following statement:

```
select First_Interesting_Field, Second_Interesting_Field, * 
from A_Table_With_Many_Columns
```

Then they will go and modify the data in the grid. However, when saving this data, it results in a concurrency violation (`DBConcurrencyException`). This worked fine with the connected RecordSets of VB6 but not so well in C#. I have tried a myriad of solutions to no avail.

1. Does anyone know how to handle this exception in a generic way? (Remember, the user can type ANY select statement or join etc. into the query editor)
2. Does anyone know how I might manipulate the columns returned such that I delete the 2 columns that appear further on in the list? (My difficulty here is that if the column name in the database is `EMail` so I do `select Email, * from Blah` the 2 pertinent columns returned are `EMail` and ADO.NET or C# aliases the second `EMail` column from the `*` portion of the query as `EMail1` so I am not able to detect the second column as a duplicate and remove it)
3. Does anyone have an alternate solution I have not thought of?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does the query return a DataTable object?

Comment: Yes it does end up in a DataTable bound to an Infragistics UltraGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could rename all variables to something like email_userdefined by doing something like this:

SELECT First_Interesting_Field as First_Interesting_Field_userdefined, Second_Interesting_Field as Second_Interesting_Field_userdefined, * 
from A_Table_With_Many_Columns

Replace user_defined with whatever you want, like order number or anything else user acceptable

Comment: I tried this to no avail.  I aliased the 2 individually selected columns.  Conversely, if I DON'T alias the first iteration of the column in the 2 individually selected columns before the "*", c# or ADO.NET aliases the 2 corresponding columns from the "Select * ".  Yet the concurrency violation still exists.